# How do I check (in shell) whether I have a valid Kerberos ticket for a specific service?

Tags: bash, kerberos

I would like to be able to check (in my `bash` script) whether I have a valid unexpired ticket for a specific service. I can get this information by hand if I do `klist`, but it would be a bit of work to programmatically parse the expiration time, service principals, etc. Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: MIT or Heimdall?

Comment: (BTW, if you *were* going to do that parsing yourself, I'd urge you to review [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001); it might be less work than you think).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am on RHEL so I believe (but not sure) that it's MIT. How do I confirm? Thanks!

Comment: `rpm -qf "$(command -v klist)"` might be a place to start.

Comment: I have `krb5-workstation-1.10.3-42z1.31.al12.x86_64` (the RHEL is pretty old). It looks like Heimdal jumped from version 1.5.2 to 7.1, so I guess I am MIT then?

Answer (score 15):

Try `klist -s`, which should return a status code of `0` if you have a valid ticker, or `1` if not. You can then test that by looking at `$?`. For example:

```
if ! klist -s
then
    echo "kerberos ticket not valid; please run kinit"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`klist`[1](https://linux.die.net/man/1/klist) does not support the requested functionality. But it's not hard to write in bash, as @CharlesDuffy suggested:

```
if ! klist 2> /dev/null | grep -q 'Principal: <your account>@<your domain>' 
then
   echo "Error: a Kerberos ticket for <your account>@<your domain> is needed."
   exit 1
fi
```

The `2> /dev/null` discards `klist`'s error output when no tickets are cached.

Comment: As noted in the earlier answer, the `-s` option provides the requested functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306555/4455247.

From the man page for `klist` (that you linked to): "`-s` Causes  klist  to  run silently (produce no output).  klist will exit with status 1 if the credentials cache cannot be read or is expired, and with status 0 otherwise."