# Get active kerberos principal using bash

Tags: bash, kerberos

I'm working on an Hadoop secure cluster using kerberos.

After a successfull `kinit`, the command `klist` shows the following output  :

```sh
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_12345
Default principal: account@ABCDE

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/10/2020 14:47:45  09/11/2020 14:47:45  krbtgt/DDHAD@DDHAD
        renew until 09/17/2020 14:47:45
```

I try to get only the default principal, in my example : `account`

actually this command works :

```sh
klist | grep "Default principal: " | sed -E 's/Default principal: (\w*)@\w*/\1/g'
```

But is not elegant :-(

Ideally, I search a native `kerberos` command.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678787/how-do-i-check-in-shell-whether-i-have-a-valid-kerberos-ticket-for-a-specific) : I've already found the command `klist -s` to check the validity of Kerberos Ticket

Thanking you in advance for your solution :-)

Comment: It may not be elegant, I agree, but it works. I’ve used a very similar `klist|sed` for years and it has never failed me so far.

Comment: I know this is not the solution you are after, but you could simplify your existing script by writing `klist | sed -nE 's/Default principal: (\w*)@\w*/\1/gp'` and getting rid of the `grep` bit

Comment: Thanks guys, I hear your advice and I removing `grep` to simplify. I'm sure someone else will find a native command ;-)

Comment: It could also be simplified to use just `grep` which I think makes a more easily readable regex: `klist | grep -Po "(?<=Default principal: ).+(?=@)"`. Note that `-P` specifies a Perl regex (which is needed for the lookbehind and lookaheads) and `-o` is for only-matching.

Comment: Instead of all those regex, why not simply do `klist -l | awk -F '@' '/@/{print$1}'` ?